# Why Drupal 8 REST DELETE for taxonomy term returns 403

Tags: rest, drupal

I've been playing with REST API for a while and everything works fine but I have a question about DELETE verb for taxonomy terms. I configured GET, POST, PATCH and DELETE for /taxonomy/term/{term_id} using RestUI and GET, POST and PATCH works fine but DELETE always returns 403 Forbidden.

I use admin account for basic auth for simplicity and development purposes only and I do generate proper token (the same method as for POST and PATCH). Does anybody tried/tested DELETE verb for taxonomy terms or is it disabled for some reasons and that's why it always returns 403? Node DELETE works fine.